# Decode UTF-8 python list to array list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an array of string like this

```
[u'ROWKEY\ufffdACCOUNTID\ufffdACCOUNTIDDSC']
```

How do i convert the above list into the below array list in python

```
['ROWKEY','ACCOUNTID','ACCOUNTIDDSC']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should encode your string not decode**. Your provided list (array of string as you mentioned) consists of a unicode sting. To represent a unicode string as a string of bytes is known as encoding, use `u'...'.encode(encoding)`. Then by using `string.split()` you can break that encoded string down into smaller chunks, or strings.

```
lst = [u'ROWKEY\ufffdACCOUNTID\ufffdACCOUNTIDDSC']
new_list = [i.encode('utf8') for i in lst[0].split(u'\ufffd')]
print(new_list)
```

Output would be:

```
['ROWKEY', 'ACCOUNTID', 'ACCOUNTIDDSC']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
old_list = [u'ROWKEY\ufffdACCOUNTID\ufffdACCOUNTIDDSC']
new_list = old_list[0].split(u'\ufffd')
print(new_list)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split()`

```
>>> [u'ROWKEY\ufffdACCOUNTID\ufffdACCOUNTIDDSC'][0].split(u"\ufffd")
[u'ROWKEY', u'ACCOUNTID', u'ACCOUNTIDDSC']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex. `re.split`

**Ex:**

```
import re

l = u'ROWKEY\ufffdACCOUNTID\ufffdACCOUNTIDDSC'
print(re.split(r"[^a-zA-Z]", l))
```

**Output:**

```
[u'ROWKEY', u'ACCOUNTID', u'ACCOUNTIDDSC']
```